# variance of difference of two means $\bar X-\bar Y$

Tags: central-limit-theorem

For the mean of sample $\bar X$, $\frac {\bar X -\mu}{\sigma_X/\sqrt{N}}$ has normal distribution. According to CLT, $\bar X$ has a variance of $\sigma_x/\sqrt{N}$.

For two means $\bar X, \bar Y$ of two samples, according to $\bar X-\bar Y=\frac{(X_1+\dots+X_M)-(Y_1+\dots+Y_N)}{M+N}=\frac{M\bar X-N \bar Y}{M+N}$ would have a deviation of $\frac { {M \sigma_x^2+N\sigma_y^2}}{(M+N)^2}$, and so $\frac {\bar X-\bar Y}{\frac {\sqrt {M \sigma_x^2+N\sigma_y^2}}{M+N}}$ has a normal distribution, right?

But *Data Anal of Life Sci* (Michael Love) says that$\frac {\bar X-\bar Y} {\sqrt {\sigma_x^2/M+\sigma_y^2/N}}$ has a normal distribution; and that $\bar X-\bar Y$ has a variance of ${\sqrt {\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2}}/\sqrt N$.
Where does it go wrong?

Comment: It seems that the author sometimes assumes the two sample sizes are N, as here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/401214/301417 (but even if so it should be 2$\sqrt N$ in the denominator, right?); sometimes assume that the two sample sizes are M and N separately.

Comment: It's important to pay attention to the context.  It's highly likely the second formula is proposed in the context of a hypothesis test; and the specific null and alternative hypotheses are important determinants of a good test statistic.

Comment: Are you assuming both samples have the same mean? When using "normal", do you mean "standard normal"?

Comment: The equality$$\bar X-\bar Y=\frac{X_1+\dots+X_M+Y_1+\dots+Y_N}{M+N}$$is definitely wrong.

Comment: In the last line do you mean _deviation_ instead of _variance_?

Comment: I correct it. Yes, standard normal. And null hypothesis is that the two means equal.

Comment: Yes. It’s deviation.

Comment: The equality$$\bar X-\bar Y=\frac{(X_1+\dots+X_M)-(Y_1+\dots+Y_N)}{M+N}$$is equally wrong.

Comment: correct it in my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar X$ has variance $\frac{\sigma_x^2}{M}$ and $\bar Y$ has variance $\frac{\sigma_y^2}{N}$

If the two samples are independent then $\bar X - \bar Y$ has variance $\frac{\sigma_x^2}{M}+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{N}$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_x^2}{M}+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{N}}$

If then $M=N$ then $\bar X - \bar Y$ has variance $\frac{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2}{N}$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2}{N}}=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2}}{\sqrt{N}}$

Comment: I see it’s $\bar X-\bar Y$, there is no difference in weights (according to sizes of the two samples) of the two variables...or say it’s not weighted sum.

Comment: That is, $\bar X-\bar Y=\frac{(X_1+\dots+X_M)}M-\frac{(Y_1+\dots+Y_N)}N$. I made a mistake here.     What I calculated in the post was mean of the two samples put together, i.e. weighted sum of means gotten from two means.